# Intermittent Blank CustomerID and Email

Tags: orders

Every so often a customer will place an order where there is no customer data for `customer_id` or `email` in the `sales_flat_order` table.

Info is present for billing and shipping in `sales_flat_quote_address`.  When this happens, the user is marked as `Guest` and is listed as a retail customer.

Has anyone seen this before or know why it might be happening?

Please let me know if there's any more info I can provide.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you implying that guest orders normally have a valid customer_id stored on the sales_flat_order table with the order record? What version of Magento are you running, and do you have customizations on the checkout process?

Comment: Ordinarily, they do not have customer_id's but they do have customer_email.  I am running 1.12.0.2 (Enterprise).  We may have customizations in the checkout process, not sure.

Comment: Are these orders placed by the customer on the frontend or the backend? I've never heard of the email simply not being captured on the order. Is it possible there is a pattern to which orders are exhibiting this behavior? A type of payment method being used perhaps?

Comment: frontend.  I can tell by the IP address.  It happens so rarely that it's hard to find a pattern.  I am looking.  Will post if I find anything.

Comment: Did you ever? I've the same problem here.